What is Performance based on?
What is website Performance based on? If SEO and the other categories are all above 90%, how can the performance be 35%? I tested a website and all the categories ranked high except for Performance on Mobile. Hence, why I'm wondering what the Performance stats are based on?
Thanks for your help.
This question is irrelevant to my enquiry. I've tried "nothing" so nothing "hasn't worked". I just want to know what Performance is based on?

On the Lighthouse result page, there are links that show you exactly what the performance score is comprised of.

When you hit that link, you'll be shown a detailed report.

